# updating rubygems to specific version on mac

Tags: rubygems, version

I need to update rubygems from 1.3.5 to 1.4.2 but apparently rubygems update just updates you to the latest version

How can I update to 1.4.2?

Answer (score 6):

You can install specific versions of RubyGems using [RVM](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/%20RVM).

```
rvm rubygems 1.4.2
```

Comment: I'd like to know how to do this too, without using RVM.

Answer (score 5):

After some research this worked for me:

```
gem install -v 1.4.2 rubygems-update && ruby `gem env gemdir`/gems/rubygems-update-1.4.2/setup.rb
```

If you need to use sudo to install gems then make sure to put a `sudo` in both calls:

```
sudo gem install -v 1.4.2 rubygems-update && sudo ruby `gem env gemdir`/gems/rubygems-update-1.4.2/setup.rb
```